# D3.js : Loading js file after html

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, single-page-application

I am building a SPA, and I want to use d3.js for graph representations in one of my pages.

My issue is that the index.html loads first, with the `<script>` and what not, and at this point the
`<div ng-view></div>`
is not filled yet. So I can't load my d3 javascript, which needs the DOM to be loaded to access DOM items via selectors :

`var svg = d3.select("#svgBarChart").append("svg")...`
that refers to
`<div id="svgBarChart"></div>` situated in dashboard.html (see below)

So what I would like to do is :

1) wait index.html to be loaded, as well as all the scripts and css

2) the index.js loads the required page. In the scenario I am loading http://myurl/#/dashboard, so the routeProvider module loads the correct html (dashboard.html) and link it to the correct controller (included in dashboard.js, already loaded from index.html). That is working fine

3) When dashboard.html is loaded, it runs the script that I inserted into it, which is the d3 script. If I load the script at the end of the .html file, it should load it after all DOM elements are loaded, right ? At the moment, if I do this, the script is loaded but I think it does not find the div.

Here is the dashboard.html part

```
<div id="svgBarChart"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/js/d3dashboard.js"></script>
```

And that gives me the following error in the browser console

```
index.js:248 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of null
  at getSVGNode (index.js:248)
  at tip (index.js:33)
  at ut.call (d3.min.js:2)
  at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (d3dashboard.js:32)
  at j (jquery.min.js:2)
  at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
  at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
  at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.min.js:2)
```

I looked into index.js (the d3 file) at line 248 :

```
function getSVGNode(el) {
  el = el.node()
  if(el.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'svg')
    return el

  return el.ownerSVGElement
}
```

So the `el` is null, which means that it didnt find the div element, right ?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it helps if you put your D3 code inside this, to ensure that the DOM is fully rendered/ loaded before executing D3 specific code.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  //do d3 stuff here
});
```

If you are using jQuery, you can use this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //do d3 stuff here
});
```